# WPF binding to external style

Tags: wpf, styles

I have found a framework called VIBlend http://viblend.com/products/net/wpf/controls/free-wpf-controls.aspx. I have downloaded it and there is a dll file containing styles. It contains a dll which contains styles. One of these Styles is contained in a file called ListBox.xaml (compiled in the dll).

It contains a few styles. One of them is declared like this:

Now i am wondering how I can use this style. If created a reference to that dll but now?
I tried this one but it does not work...

```
<UserControl.Resources>
<ResourceDictionary x:Key="listBoxStyle" Source="Office2010SilverListBoxStyle"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" Style="{StaticResource listBoxStyle}">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary
        Source="/PutDllNameHere;component/ListBox.xaml" />
</Application.Resources>
```